# Error response from daemon when i'm trying docker pull peterevans/nominatim

Tags: linux, docker, openstreetmap, nominatim, osrm

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `~/.docker/config.json`. Docker registry proxy settings stored there.

More info about using proxy: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

Comment: the file not found in home directory of the containers

Comment: This file is located in your user home directory on host machine.

Comment: try to run ``docker info | grep Proxy`` on your host machine

Comment: WARNING: No swap limit support
HTTP Proxy: http://proxy.example.com:80/